# Use sessionRegistry without session count limit for user?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

To use

```
@Autovired
SessionRegistry sessionRegistry
```

in my code I have added following configuration:

```
http.sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
```

But I don't want to limit maximum sessions.

Can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

`-1` - special value to say spring don't limit user sessions

```
http.sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(-1)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#list-authenticated-principals

Answer (score 0):

Add this to enable multiple logins of same user with different sessions but invalidates the old session with the start of the new.

```
http.sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).and().enableSessionUrlRewriting(false)
.sessionFixation().newSession()
```

Comment: sessionRegistry() returns ConcurrencyControlConfigurer which doesn't have sessionFixation() method